# Lower bound for the number of representations of integers as sum of squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, lattices, sums-of-squares, theta-functions

Let $k\geq 4$. As usual, let $r_k(n)$ denote the number of ways to represent $n$ as the sum of $k$ squares. Is this true that for every $\varepsilon>0$, one has $r_k(n) \gg n^{\frac{k}{2}-1-\varepsilon}$ ? Is there an easy proof of this fact? What can we say about the cases $k=2,3$?

Many thanks !

Comment: For $k=2$, some positive integers are not the sum of two squares and some are in very few ways.

Comment: This appears false for $k=4$ for primes. Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem

Comment: For $k=4$ what you want follows from Jacobi; and then for all $k\ge 5$ follows easily by induction on $k$ (for example).  For $k=3$ the number of representations of $n$ as a sum of three squares is a class number; and the inequality holds by Siegel's theorem.

Comment: @Lucia: Of course for $k=4$ there is a $2$-adic obstruction. The lower bound is fine if $n$ is not divisible by a fixed power of $2$.

Comment: Jacobis identity (and modular forms and dimension counting) is not the only way to approach this problem. See the Hardy Littlewood circle method, which can be much more flexible in certain situations.

Comment: For $k\ge5$, the circle method actually gives an asymptotic formula for $r_k(n)$ which is even stronger than the desired lower bound.

Comment: @joro: for $k=4$ and $n$ an odd prime, the formula you linked to gives $r_k(n) = 8(n+1) \gg n^{1-\varepsilon}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, I will check the Hardy-Littlewood circle method. @GregMartin, do you have some references for me?

Comment: @Stabilo: For the Hardy-Littlewood circle method, the standard reference is Vaughan's book. You can find the asymptotic formula for $k\geq 5$ there (and also for the sum of $m$-th powers when $k\geq 2^m+1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k=4$, your statement would be that $r_4(n) \gg n^{1-\epsilon}$. This is false. [Jacobi's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_four-square_theorem) can be stated as that $r_4(n)/8$ is the sum of the divisors of $n$ that are not divisible by $4$. Let $n = 2^t m$ with $m$ odd and $t$ positive. $r_4(n) = 24 \sigma (m)$ independent of $t$. In particular, for $m=1$, you can express $n=2^t$ as a sum of $4$ squares in $24$ ways, scaled up versions of the $24$ ways to express $2$ and $4$ as sums of $4$ squares. $24$ doesn't grow with $n$.

For $k=4$, $n$ odd, the statement is trivially true (after Jacobi's four-square theorem) since the odd divisors of $n$ include $n$ itself.

For $k \gt 4$ this follows easily by reducing to the case of $k=4$, $n$ odd. Choose the first $k-4$ squares to be at most $\frac{n/2}{k-4}$ so that the remainder is odd. This can be done in about $\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{n/2}{k-4}\right)^{(k-4)/2}$ ways. You can complete each of these to a representation of $n$ as a sum of $k$ squares in at least $n/2$ ways, so $r_k(n) \ge c(k) n^{k/2-1}$.

Comment: That is what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Complementing Douglas Zare's answer, for $k=3$ see the responses [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217698/many-representations-as-a-sum-of-three-squares).

Regarding the case of $k=2$, the number of representations $r_2(n)$ as a sum of two squares is often zero (so there is no lower bound), but it behaves much like $d_2(n)$. Indeed, superficially the first quantity counts the number of representations $n=a^2+b^2$, while the second quantity counts the number of representations $n=ab$. At a deeper level, $r_2(n)$ equals $4\sum_{d\mid n}\chi(n)$, where $\chi$ is the nontrivial Dirichlet character modulo $4$, while $d_2(n)$ equals $\sum_{d\mid n} 1$ by definition. At any rate, the large values of $r_2(n)$ are much the same as those of $d_2(n)$, i.e. these functions have similar maximal order etc. (For $r_2(n)$ the largest values are produced by the products $n=q_1q_2\dots q_k$, where $q_1<q_2<\dots$ is the sequence of primes congruent to $1$ modulo $4$.)

Comment: I like this point of view, thank you for sharing it!

Comment: @GH from Mo, on a slightly different note, would you happen to have a nice reference in mind for the computation of $r_2(n)$?

Comment: @user96343: See Theorem 278 in Hardy-Wright: An introduction to the theory of numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much!