# Sums of four coprime squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

The Four Squares Theorem says that every natural number is the sum of four squares in $\mathbb Z$. What is known about coprime representations? Here we call a presentation $n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ coprime if the g.c.d. of the four numbers $a,b,c,d$ is 1. Does every natural number have a coprime presentation? If not, is there a simple criterion characterising the numbers that have coprime presentations? What is known about the number of different coprime presentations of a given $n$?

Comment: If $8|n$ then you must have all the four variables being even.  Apart from that you can establish the result by Mobius inversion and using Jacobi's result on sums of four squares.

Comment: @Lucia: Could you please explain that? I don't quite get it, sorry.

Comment: If $n$ is odd (for simplicity) and you write $n = rs^2$ where $r$ is square-free, then your question is equivalent to checking whether $\sum_{a | s} \mu(a) \sum_{b | r(s/a)^2} b \geq 1$. The arithmetic seems annoying... but if you further assume that $\gcd(r,s) = 1$ then this is equivalent to checking whether $\sum_{a | s} \mu(a) \sigma((s/a)^2) \geq 1$, since $\sigma(r)$ would factor out (here $\sigma$ is the sum of divisors function). Note that $\sigma(s^2)$ is also multiplicative, so Mobius inversion would work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $R(n)$ denote the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of $4$ squares, and $r(n)$ the number of ways where gcd of $(a,b,c,d) =1$.  Then grouping representations of $n$ as a sum of $4$ squares according to the gcd of the variables, clearly we have 
$$ 
R(n) = \sum_{k^2 | n} r(n/k^2),
$$ 
and so by Mobius inversion 
$$ 
r(n) = \sum_{k^2| n} \mu(k) R(n/k^2). 
$$

Now by Jacobi's four square theorem, $R(n)$ is given explicitly as $8$ times a multiplicative function $F(n)$ defined on prime powers by 
$$ 
F(2^k) = 3 \text{ for all } k\ge 1,
$$ 
and, for odd primes $p$,
$$ 
F(p^k) = p^k + p^{k-1} + \ldots + 1. 
$$
So $r(n)$ is $8$ times a multiplicative function $f(n)$ which is defined on prime powers by 
$$
f(2)= 3; \ \ f(4) = 2;\ \  f(2^k)=0 \text{ for } k \ge 3,
$$
and for odd primes $p$ and $k\ge 1$ 
$$ 
f(p^k) = p^k + p^{k-1}.
$$

Comment: Good to have this on record! For the interested reader: there is a similar (but somewhat deeper) formula for the sum of 3 coprime squares. See our responses at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217698/many-representations-as-a-sum-of-three-squares

Comment: I am wondering if there is a formula for the number of representations where every summand is coprime to any other.

Answer (score 7):

As Lucia noticed, if $8\mid n$, then $a,b,c$, and $d$ must be even, so that there is no "co-prime representation". If $8\nmid n$ with $n$ large enough, one can argue as follows.

Find a positive integer $d<\sqrt n$ such that

- $d$ is co-prime with $n$;
- $d$ and $n$ are of different parity;
- moreover, if $n\equiv 3\pmod 8$, then $d\equiv 0\pmod 4$, and if $n\equiv 7\pmod 8$, then $d\equiv 2\pmod 4$.

One readily verifies that $d^2\not\equiv n+1\pmod 8$, as a result of which $n-d^2$ is not of the form $4^u(8v+7)$ (where $u$ and $v$ are non-negative integers). Therefore, by [Legendre's three-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), $n-d^2$ is a sum of three squares: $n-d^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$. This yields $n=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$, and co-primality of $d$ and $n$ ensures that $\gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$.