# Large values of $L(1,\chi)$ for quadratic Dirichlet characters $\chi$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Granville and Soundararajan, in "Upper Bounds for $L(1, \chi)$", first paragraph,
say it is known that there exist quadratic Dirichlet characters $\chi$ for which $L(1, \chi)$ is about $\log\log q$,
where $q$ is the conductor of $\chi$.   Those authors gave no reference, and I can't
find one so far.  Can anyone point me to a reference?

Comment: You will find the answer in the answers to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/217698/many-representations-as-a-sum-of-three-squares). Also, please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now. Finally, please use TeX on this site.